# anomaly detection: feature calculation problem

Tags: ids

I have a question about how to calculate features selected in [ 1 ]. It assumes that the impact of DoS attack on features are `nSrcs=nDsts=1, nPkts/sec>a, nSYN/Pkts>b, ...` (Table 1 of [ 1 ])

Number of sources (`nSrcs`) and number of destination (`nDsts`) and other features are calculated for each aggregated flow according to destination IP (`IPdst`) in this case, in a time slot. (Section 5.1 of [ 1 ])

But how is it possible for a web server which receives lots of flows from different sources (`nSrcs>1`) to match with the mentioned DoS criteria. Maybe I don't understand what aggregation means here.

Reference: 
[ 1 ] Pedro Casas, Johan Mazel, Philippe Owezarski, [Unsupervised Network Intrusion Detection Systems: Detecting the Unknown without Knowledge](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0140366412000266), Computer Communications, 2012.

Edit: Available at [here](http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/73/62/78/PDF/paper_comcom_2011.pdf). (This manuscript differs from the published one a little bit)

Edit: I asked the author, and answered this way:

> "Everything is wrong with your reasonning as you consider basic
>   traffic figures and not statistical figures. First, you need to learn
>   about what an anomaly or a DoS attack is. Then, you have to learn
>   about traffic statistics in the Internet... There are many papers on
>   this written during the two last decades. Read them first."

what are statistical figures of network traffic?

Comment: I doubt you will get many answers to this if we have to pay $40 to read the study you are linking to. I suggest you put enough information in your question that it can be answered.

Comment: Try here: http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/73/62/78/PDF/paper_comcom_2011.pdf

Comment: Yasser - can you clarify what your question is actually asking. It doesn't appear you are asking about calculating features, but I couldn't understand what you are asking.

Comment: I asked how nSrcs is calculated. If I aggregated flows that are sent to a webserver according to IPdst, then always nSrcs>1. So never DoS attack condition is satisfied.

Comment: Can you articulate that in English - I still can't understand, and I'm guessing the downvotes and close votes are for that reason.

Comment: Sorry that I can't make it clear. Lets consider that we have a webserver at IPA:port80. client1 connects to it, so there is a flow IPclient1:port1->IPA:port80. client2 connects so there is a flow IPclient2:port2->IPA:port80. Now what aggregation with IPdst means here? are the two flows going to be considered as one object. Then we have nSrcs=2. So if IPclient1 is doing DoS attack, how the condition of DoS attack is satisfied (nSrcs=nDsts=1)?

Comment: @DavidWachtfogel Just curious... how did you locate that PDF?

Comment: I think your question is missing quite a bit of context, unless it's somewhere in those dozens of pages of article. I suggest you clarify your question to the point where someone other than the article's original author would be able to answer it.

Comment: @makerofthings7 In this case Google - but it's generally a good site for finding papers

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking: "With regards to IDS monitoring, what are "traffic statistics" and where can I learn about them? (whitepapers etc)"... then I think the answer you seek is in the whitepaper itself.  And there is a picture that illustrates this concept on the top of page 3.

> **2. Related Work & Contributions**
>
> /Snip...
>
> The problem of network anomaly detection has been extensively studied
>   during the last decade. Most approaches analyze statistical variations
>   of traffic volume descriptors (e.g., no. of packets, bytes, or new
>   flows) and/or par- ticular traffic features (e.g., distribution of IP
>   addresses and ports), using either single link measurements or net-
>   work wide data. A non-exhaustive list of standard meth- ods includes
>   the use of signal processing techniques (e.g., ARIMA modeling,
>   wavelets-based filtering) on single-link traffic measurements [9],
>   Kalman filters [12] for network- wide anomaly detection, and Sketches
>   applied to IP-flows [14, 15].
>
> [9] P. Barford, J. Kline, D. Plonka, and A. Ron, “A Signal Analysis of
>   Network Traffic Anomalies”, in Proc. ACM IMW, 2002.
>
> [12] A. Soule, K. Salamatian, and N. Taft, “Combining Filtering and
>   Statistical Methods for Anomaly Detection”, in Proc. ACM IMC, 2005.
>
> [14] B. Krishnamurthy, S. Sen, Y. Zhang, and Y. Chen, “Sketch- based
>   Change Detection: Methods, Evaluation, and Applica- tions”, in Proc.
>   ACM IMC, 2003.
>
> [15] G. Dewaele, K. Fukuda, P. Borgnat, P. Abry, and K. Cho, “Ex-
>   tracting Hidden Anomalies using Sketch and non Gaussian Multi-
>   resolution Statistical Detection Procedures”, in Proc. LSAD, 2007.

If you find links for any of those whitepapers, kindly add them as a comment to this answer; I'd be curious about reading them.

Comment: Surprisingly, this part that you quote here is not in the published version of this paper that I got from sciencedirect.com. and also the references.

Comment: @YasserMZadeh - I got this from the link you posted : http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/73/62/78/PDF/paper_comcom_2011.pdf  (how did you find that link)

Comment: I didn't find it. David Wachtfogel found it as you see in the comments below my question. I was wondering how he could find either.

Comment: I tried this and got it as the first result from google: "{TITLE OF PAPER}+manuscript"

Comment: [9] http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~pb/paper_imw_02.pdf - [12]
http://static.usenix.org/event/imc05/tech/full_papers/soule/soule.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In table 1 of the paper, the authors describe the characteristics of different types of attacks. Some of them have nSrcs=1, some don't. Specifically, what they classify as a DOS attack has NSrcs=1.

You ask "but what if there are two sources?". Well, then you have what they classify as a DDOS, where the definition includes nSrcs > 1.

Now, in practical information security we don't use those exact definitions (we consider DDOS as a subset of DOS, and to have more attributes than just nSrcs>1), which perhaps explains your confusion, but if they need to classify attacks that way for their paper, then fair enough.

Practical classifications of anything are, inevitably, likely to be a bit mushy around the edges, and need tightening up if you're going to do some maths with them.